# How can you cast a nested HashMap in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, casting

There is an ArrayList that has nested HashMaps. It's easy to get the value from the parent HashMap, but when I try to get the value from the nested HashMap (child), I get ClassCastException. This is a sample how it looks like (similar to the previous post):

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

HashMap<String, Object> parentHash = new HashMap<String, Object>();
HashMap<String, String> childHash = new HashMap<String, String>();

childHash.put("child_id", "id")
childHash.put("name", "first last");
childHash.put("sex", "man");

parentHash.put("parent_id", "id");
parentHash.put("name", "first last");
parentHash.put("sex", "woman");

parentHash.put("children", childHash);
data.add(parentHash);
```

To cast, I use the following code (sadly, I get ClassCastException):

```
Map<String, String> fetchedChildData = (Map<String, String>) data.get(position).get("children");
showAlert("Test", "Ok", (String) fetchedChildData.get("child_id"));
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Errorlist:

```
    04-03 17:34:01.640: W/dalvikvm(26248): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248):    at com.on_d_mand.live_dashboard.EventListMenu$2.onItemClick(EventListMenu.java:265)
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3740)
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1992)
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
04-03 17:34:01.645: E/AndroidRuntime(26248):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I don't think you need get(position). Try this. Map<String, String> fetchedChildData = (Map<String, String>) parentContainer.get("children");

Comment: What is parentContainer? Can you show how you define and populate it?

Comment: Is `parentContainer` the same as `data`? Please explain.

Comment: You should seriously consider the propositions made in your previous questions as you keep stumbling on the same problems and the solutions provided in the answers to your earlier question also avoid the situation you are encountering here

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant data instead of parentContainer. I'm fetching JSON objects and placing the keys + values in a new HashMap and storing the new HashMap content in an ArrayList similar like the example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON objects being represented as a "map" or "dictionnary" does not mean you should represent it equally in Java. Objects are there for this purpose!

I suggest you have an object that will parse the associated JSON and construct itself from it. For instance:

```
public class User {

  public User() {
    name = "";
    friends = new ArrayList<User>();
  }

  /** Create a User from a JSON Object **/
  public static User createFromJson(JSONObject json) {
    User u = new User();

    // Read simple fields of the JSON object
    u.name = json.optString("name");

    // Now recursively read other users from a "friend" property
    JSONArray jsonFriends = json.optJSONArray("friends");
    for (int i=0; i<jsonFriends.length(); ++i) {
      // This is the next nested JSON Object
      JSONObject jsonFriend = jsonFriends.getJSONObject(i);

      // We convert it to a Java object
      User friend = User.createFromJson(jsonFriend);

      // And add it to our friend list
      u.friends.add(friend);
    }
  }

  private String name;
  private List<User> friends;
}
```

That class would nicely read a JSON such as:

```
{ 
  "name": "Joe",
  "friends": [
    {
      "name": "Jack"
    },
    {
      "name": "Rose"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I'll try it when I'm at home and also mark it correct when it works.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me on Java 6.  Maybe it's a bug with Android Dalvik?

Anyway, I agree you should consider creating your own classes ("Parent", "Child", etc) and using the [composite design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), rather than using collections within collections within collections.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
HashMap<String, Object> parentHash = new HashMap<String, Object>();
HashMap<String, String> childHash = new HashMap<String, String>();

childHash.put("child_id", "id");
childHash.put("name", "first last");
childHash.put("sex", "man");

parentHash.put("parent_id", "id");
parentHash.put("name", "first last");
parentHash.put("sex", "woman");

parentHash.put("children", childHash);
data.add(parentHash);

Map<String, String> fetchedChildData = 
    (Map<String, String>) data.get(0).get("children");

// prints: child_id=id
System.out.println("child_id=" + fetchedChildData.get("child_id"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
int position = 0;
Map<String, Object> parent = data.get(position);
Map<String, String> child = (Map<String, String>) parent.get("children");
```

Comment: then you probably should correct the following in your question: `parentHash.get(position)` to `data.get(position)`

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I meant data. But the problem is, that it still doesn't work...